# Haskell stack cant find installed ghc

Tags: linux, haskell-stack

A project that already has been set up is unable to find the GHC.
Stack build results in:

```
No compiler found, expected minor version match with ghc-8.0.2 (x86_64-ncurses6-nopie)
(based on resolver setting in /home/iam/Work/has/grove/stack.yaml).
To install the correct GHC into /home/iam/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/, try running "stack
setup" or use the "--install-ghc" flag. To use your system GHC installation,
run "stack config set system-ghc --global true", or use the "--system-ghc" flag.
```

Stack setup results in:

```
Unable to find installation URLs for OS key: linux64-ncurses6-nopie
However, in .stack-work, in the install file there is a folder called x86_64-linux-ncurses6,
not linux64-ncurses6-nopie
```

Stack was installed by pacman.
Version 1.4.0 x86_64, the project is using resolver: lts-8.21

Comment: I can confirm this issue.

Comment: I also confirm this. Even the system wide ghc cound't be found

Comment: So frustrating, a whole day has been lost. I've tried to use system-ghc option, lots of Linker erros...

Comment: Would you have the stack.yaml?

Comment: @Reactormonk what do you mean? Show the stack.yaml? What are the options that can be set there to solve the problem?

Comment: I have another Arch installation and that one works... with OS key as ghc-nopie-8.02

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is known upstream. (https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3268). As suggested in this issue, installing libtinfo from AUR helps, since there is a `tinfo-nopie` bindist of GHC. I have not yet run into the problems reported by TimoFreiberg (who is working on providing an `ncurses6-nopie` bindist) in this issue report.

Comment: `ncurses5-compat-libs` is also necessary

Comment: Only installing `ncurses5-compat-libs` did it for me.